# What type of sequences would these be?

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-progressions

So as far as I can tell, there are two types of possible sequences:

1. Arithmetic sequences $\to$ Where there's a linear/quadratic/cubic/... progression i.e. with a formula of $c_yn^y+c_{y-1}n^{y-1}+c_{y-2}n^{y-2}+\dots+c_0$
2. Geometric sequences $\to$ Where the ratio between a term and that before it is constant i.e. with a formula of $a^n$

I'm not sure if I'm correct so far, so please correct me if I'm not!

As we can see, geometric sequences are primarily defined by calculating the exponent of a certain number. But what if you added several of these together?

So, if a formula for a sequence was $2^n + 3^n - 4^n + 5^n$, what type of sequence would it be? Also, how would it be solved if you were just given the terms?

Taking this one step further, what if the formula for the sequence was $2n^2 - 3n + 5^n - 4^n + 5\cdot(2^n)$? How would this be solved?

Comment: An arithmetic sequence is **not** what you wrote, and besides these two  there are infinite types of sequences more...

Comment: @DonAntonio Then what *is* it?? Also, I've been told that there are only these two types by every teacher I've had...

Comment: My goodness, where did you go to school? I find it hard to believe that _all_ your teachers could give you such bad misinformation.

Comment: @DavidK  I'm *still in* (secondary) school (Year 10), so it's possible I haven't reached an advanced enough level yet...

Comment: In general it is not possible to deduce a rule for a sequence just from a finite number of terms. You may be able to do it if you have been told something about the rule (such as, “the sum of four exponentials”) and have the values of a sufficient number of known terms.

Comment: Thanks! I think I understand the part about there being an infinite number of possible sequences for a finite number of terms.

Comment: @Adi219 A sequence $\;\{a_n\}\;$ is (1) arithmetic if for every $\;n\ge1\;,\;\;a_{n+1}-a_n=d=\,$ constant, and (2) geometric if for every $\;n\ge1\;,\;\;\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=q=\,$ constant. You wrote the second one correctly but not the first one, though there is no such thing as "...with a formula of $\;a_n\,$ " . As an advise, google the terms and read carefully.

Comment: @DonAntonio The second one means Tn = a^n

Answer (score 1):

I feel like I need to expand on the comments of @DonAntonio and @David K.

First of all, an arithmetic sequence is a sequence where the difference of any $2$ consecutive terms is constant (notice the similarity with the geometric one). Notice that there are infinitely many sequences besides the $2$ types you listed- take for example

$$1,0,0,0,0,0,0\dots$$

defined by $a_1=1, a_n=0$ for $n\geq2$. This is neither an arithemetic progression nor a geometric one.

In particular, a sequence is a function $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow S$ where $S$ is an object and the sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is defined as

$$a_i=f(i)$$

Since you can make the function arbitrary, there are **a lot** of sequences not satisfying neither of the $2$ properties you stated.

Also, you can see that even if you have a finite number of terms, then unless you are told something about the general form of the sequence, you are not able to find a **unique**  sequence which starts the same as the finitely many terms you have since again, you can set the next entry to be an arbitrary one.

Having said all of this, informally you can think of a sequence as a list of objects (numbers in your case). Since you can list your objects however you like, you see that there is no general rule for determining a sequence.